# Call to a member function get_listkary() on a non-object

Tags: json, codeigniter

I have controller that has error whenever i run it. I've Checked over and over again but can't find where is the mistake. the error is :

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined property:  Assetfilter::$Assetfiltermdl

Filename: controllers/Assetfilter.php

Line Number: 29

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function get_listkary() on a non-object in **C:\wamp\www\asset_apps
\application\controllers\Assetfilter.php** on line **29**

Please Help.

This is my controller :

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Assetfilter extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('user');
    $this->load->model('assetfiltermdl');
    $this->load->model('worklistmdl');
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->model('email_ctrl');
    $this->datauser = $this->session->userdata('logged_id');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('My_PHPMailer');
    //Do your magic here
}

//update 20 oct 2016 list kary.

public function kary_reload()
{
    $list = $this->Assetfiltermdl->get_listkary();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $listkary) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $listkary->$idnik;
        $row[] = $listkary->kodenik;
        $row[] = $listkary->namakary;
        $row[] = $listkary->namaper;
        $row[] = $listkary->iddept;
        $row[] = $listkary->jabatan;
        $row[] = $listkary->flagstatus;

        $row[] = '<a href="<?php echo base_url(' . "'" . 'asset/karyawandetailform' . "'" .'); ?>/<?php echo $listkary[' . "'" . 'idnik' . "'" . '] ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"> Detail</a>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(' . "'" . 'asset/karyawaneditform' . "'" . '); ?>/<?php echo $listkary[' . "'" . 'idnik' . "'" .'] ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(' . "'" . 'asset/karyawandeleform' . "'" . ');    ?>/<?php echo $listkary[' . "'" . 'idnik' . "'" .'] ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="javascript:return confirm(' . "'" . 'Apakah Anda Sudah Yakin ?' . "'" . ')"  >Del</a>';

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->assetfiltermdl->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->assetfiltermdl->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

}

This Is My Model:

```
<?php 

 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Assetfiltermdl extends CI_Model {

    var $kary_table = 'listkary';
    var $kary_column_order = array(null, 'update_date'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $kary_column_search = array('idper','iddept','namakary','kodenik'); //set column field database for datatable searchable 
    var $kary_order = array('update_date' => 'desc'); // default order 

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

//update 20 oct 2016

  public function get_listkary()
    {
      $this->_get_listkary_query();
      echo $this->db->last_query();
      //if($_POST['length'] != -1)
      //$this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      echo $this->db->last_query();
      return $query->result();
    }

  private function _get_listkary_query()
    {

      //add custom filter here
      if($this->input->post('idper'))
      {
        $this->db->where('idper', $this->input->post('idper'));
      }
      if($this->input->post('iddept'))
      {
        $this->db->where('iddept', $this->input->post('iddept'));
      }
      //if($this->input->post('idsubdept'))
      //{
      //  $this->db->like('LastName', $this->input->post('LastName'));
      //}
      if($this->input->post('kodenik'))
      {
        $this->db->like('kodenik', $this->input->post('kodenik'));
      }
      if($this->input->post('namakry'))
      {
        $this->db->like('namakary', $this->input->post('namakry'));
      }

      $this->db->from($this->kary_table);

      $i = 0;

      foreach ($this->kary_column_search as $item) // loop column 
      {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {

          if($i===0) // first loop
          {
            $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
            $this->db->where($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
          }
          else 
          {
            if($i===1) // second loop (iddept)
            {
                $this->db->where($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);  
            }   
          }

          if(count($this->kary_column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
            $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
      }

    }

  public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->kary_table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

  function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_listkary_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}

/* End of file assetfiltermdl.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/assetfiltermdl.php */
```

and this is my view :

```
       <div class="right_col" role="main">
          <div class="">
            <div class="page-title">
              <div class="title_left">
                <h1> Data Karyawan </h1>
                    <h2> Informasi Data Karyawan </h2>
                    <p>
                        <a href ="<?php echo base_url('asset/karyawantambahform'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah Karyawan Baru</a>   
                    </p>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class = "row">

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Daftar Karyawan</h2>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">

                <form id="form-filter" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="idper" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Perusahaan</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" id="idper" name="idper">
                                <option>Pilih Perusahaan</option>
                                <?php foreach ($perushlov as $key => $value) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $value['idper']?>"><?php echo $value['namaper']?></option>}
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group" >
                        <label for="iddept" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Departemen :</label> 
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" id="iddept" name="iddept">
                                    <option >Pilih Departement</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($deptlov as $key => $value) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $value['iddept']?>"><?php echo $value['kodedept'] . ' - ' . $value['namadept'] . ' - ' . $value['namaper'] ?></option>}
                                    <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="kodenik" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama Karyawan</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namakry">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="kodenik" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode NIK</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kodenik">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="LastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <button type="button" id="btn-filter" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btn-reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </form>
                 <!-- <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered"> -->
                <table id="master_karyawan" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Kode Nik</th>
                        <th>Nama Karyawan</th>
                        <th>Perusahaan</th>
                        <th>Departemen</th>
                        <th>Jabatan</th>
                        <th>Aktif</th>
                        <th>Administrasi</th>
                    </tr>           
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var table;

$(document).ready(function() {

    //datatables
    table = $('#master_karyawan').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
       "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Assetfilter/kary_reload')?>",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function ( data ) {
                data.perush = $('#idper').val();
                data.depart = $('#iddept').val();
                data.namakry = $('#namakry').val();
                data.kodenik = $('#kodenik').val();
            }
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

    });

    $('#btn-filter').click(function(){ //button filter event click
        table.ajax.reload(null,false);  //just reload table
    });
    $('#btn-reset').click(function(){ //button reset event click
        $('#form-filter')[0].reset();
        table.ajax.reload(null,false);  //just reload table
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: ```$list = $this->Assetfiltermdl->get_listkary();``` I think this is your line number 29. May be you mentioned the caps A, that's why it is showing the error.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I replace the caps A, the error still there, but I check for the error on firebug I can't find error message. the error pop up is :      DataTables warning: table id=master_karyawan - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1. Please Help. Thanks - Dian

Comment: Remove `echo` lines from model.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your help. it's work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check in config/database.php

```
    'save_queries' => TRUE
```